# show progress in command prompt when java web application is running

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets, command-prompt

I have developed a simple application such as `insertion, updation in jsp,servlet that is java web`. What i want to do is: suppose i am inserting data into my `oracle db then data is inserted and i got a message that data has been inserted successfully`, same thing i want to show in a `command prompt` when my `web app` is running in `tomcat server`. Application will run in browser and simultaneously `command prompt` will show that :

`this data is inserted into this table---transaction committed successfully----`

How can i implement that? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: accpeted -1 but if solution is there then please help me by posting it

Comment: simple log4j will serve the purpose

Comment: Why do you want to show progress from a web app in a console window?  Web apps don't necessarily run on servers with consoles, and the client has a browser so you can't mean you want to write to the client console.  I'm not sure what you are asking.  If you *must* do something like this on the server, set up your Log4j to use a console appender.

Comment: @RayToal i want to show progress in server side console window, but if client side will access it then they can view it by installing server console window first.

Comment: any link for log4j i am trying in google but not getting my answer

Comment: @Tom clients cannot access your server console.  Sure, I suppose you could throw something together to give them access to the logs, but that's really not the best idea; if you want to give them a sense of progress, show it on your webpage.  If you're referring to the java console that shows up when you run an applet, that's completely irrelevant.  In case of a webapp, the java process only runs on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vast majority of Java web applications use [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/index.html) for logging.

To log messages to the server's console, use the Log4j [ConsoleAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/ConsoleAppender.html) class.

Normally you need to do little more than drop `log4j.jar` into your `tomcat/lib` directory, and configure logging with a `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties` file, then have your servlets or jsps or controllers or services issue logging commands.  There are many tutorials on the web that can get you started learning log4j with tomcat.

Oh and by the way, you can try plain old `System.out.println()` calls from a servlet, though this is only for learning.  Professional applications should use a logger.

Comment: +1 Ray for your answer but can web application run on servers showing progress in console?

Comment: You can show progress in a web server's console but this does not help the client at all, as clients cannot access this information.  I can only imagine this technique being useful during serverside development where the server programmer is "watching" database progress.  However this is no substitute for unit testing and proper logging.  Progress should be shown to the client in the browser.  Server side logging MAY show start timestamps and end timestamps for database queries if you like, but console progress on the server is generally not useful IMHO.  HTH.